# Deployment issue using ssh with Multiple server on Hyperledger GO SDK

Tags: ssh, hyperledger-fabric, peer

i am working on Go SDK for my hyperledger permissioned blockchain . We are deploying multiple DNS server as peers and  orderers .

After going through Yacovm  github :https://github.com/yacovm/fabricDeployment/blob/master/deploy.sh

We were facing issue when trying to ping using SSH to another peer ,also getting permission denied as a message when i tried to login to another user .

we also added authorized keys in our .ssh file but still nothing happens .

Comment: what does "ping using SSH to another peer mean"?
come to http://chat.hyperledger.org/ and ping me and we'll try to see what's your issue.